# All JSP works in local, but some failed in server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Using the same War file, everything works in local environment (). But when this war is run under a docker, load balance in front, somehow, some JSP returns 404 resource not found.  Heres more detail of the war:

For example when accessing http://server_name/auth/role-detail, the tomcat access log shows:

`"GET /auth/role-detail HTTP/1.1" 404 1017`

And the weirdest of all thing is this error message on browser (look at the "/" slash has gone missing):
[image]

I confirm the file is there: 
`/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/views/auth/role-detail.jsp`

And to add clarity, i have a ViewResolver that points to my JSP location:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");         
    return resolver;
}
```

But i can access the above from local (Windows or Vagrant) perfectly fine. Only a few jsp files in auth folder has this issue on server. Has anyone encounter such weird behaviour before?

Comment: @berger oh! my typo, i just fix the description above. thanks for pointing it out. im sure the JSP file is there, since my local runs fine.

Comment: `/WEB-INF` is considered a protected folder, and should not be exposed to access, if this is really needed, you can add some Servlet Mapping directives in web.xml as workaround though i recommend not to do this., maybe it's added locally on ur Env , that's why it works

Comment: You are using Servlet ? (I guess), no error in the mapping ? No error in the redirection to the view (JSP) when the slash might disappear

Comment: @AxelH No Mapping error. Server boots up without a single noise (Error/Warining)

Comment: @Yazan My local, also consist of an Ubuntu that runs inside a Vagrant. To me, it is as close as a server can get and it works perfectly well and able to point to all JSP without issue

Comment: that's what i am talking about using a local dev env might have some configuration that allows such behavior while on a production server/ a host server where security measures are taken to the limit, this could be not allowd

Comment: @Yazan, althought i doubt since some JSP files managed to be served, but still worth a try to see if it helps. i'll update once i test it

Comment: @Yazan i just tested it, i moved the tag lib and jsp out from WEB-INF, but same error, same old same old.

Comment: that looks strange, did you change the Resolver thing too? the `setPrefix` to be `/views/` only?

Comment: @Yazan, OF course i change the view resolver. else it will throw tons of errors.